# Set no item pre-selected in Bottom Navigation view

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm adding the new Bottom Navigation View from the material design library to a project, and I would like to have no pre selected item by default.

For now first item is selected by default.

I have used

```
mBottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
```

but when doing it in for loop for all the menu item last item is selected again by default.

Is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I am just initializing the view and using the above code in loop

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < mBottomNavigation.getMenu().size(); i++) {
      mBottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
    }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I combined the solution mentioned by @Ashish Kumar and resolved my query and

```
private void customizeBottomBar() {
        mBottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(0)
                .setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.ic_reserve_normal));
        changeMenuItemCheckedStateColor(mBottomNavigation, getUnCheckedColor(), getUnCheckedColor());
    }

/**
   * Method to change the color state of bottom bar view
   * @param bottomNavigationView - BottomNavigation view instance
   * @param checkedColorHex int value of checked color code
   * @param uncheckedColorHex int value of unchecked color code
   */
  void changeMenuItemCheckedStateColor(BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView,
      int checkedColorHex, int uncheckedColorHex) {

    int[][] states = new int[][]{
        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, // checked
    };

    int[] colors = new int[]{
        uncheckedColorHex,
        checkedColorHex
    };

    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    bottomNavigationView.setItemTextColor(colorStateList);
    bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(colorStateList);

  }
```

Answer (score 11):

Not sure about the proper way to achieve this but a work around will help-

1. `setCheckable(false)` for first item

   `navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setCheckable(false);`
2. `item.setCheckable(true) inside onNavigationItemSelected()`

   ```
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.navigation_home:
           item.setCheckable(true);
           mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
           return true;
     }
     return false;
   }
   ```

Comment: ya its working fine..Thanks a lot.one up vote for you.

Comment: @Ashish Kumar I am wondering why setChecked isnt working for 26 and above has to use setCheckable

Comment: Works but when using icons only, the text still shows, how can I remove the text from underneath?

Comment: @JaySmoke ```app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"```

Answer (score 8):

I came up with another solution

Just add one more item to your menu.xml file for example

This is my **bottom_nav_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/cart" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_wishlist"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/wish_list" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/account" />

    
    <!-- Our invisible item -->

    <item
        android:id="@+id/invisible"
        android:visible="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/account" />

</menu>
```

Notice that I have added that item at last position and given it an id `invisible` and also set it's visibility to false.

Now, In the activity just set selected item id to this id like this

```
bottomNavMenu.setSelectedItemId(R.id.invisible);
```

Thanks

Comment: This is best answer i like. Don't play with framework handle with trick until framework has functionality of none selection. Thumbs Up

Comment: Works great! To concise the solution a bit, we can just use id and visible attribute.

Comment: Won't work if you already have 5 tabs as maximum allowed tabs are 5 for BottomNavigationView. Will throw a

Answer (score 3):

**XML Code**

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item              android:id="@+id/nav_item1" />
    <item              android:id="@+id/nav_item2" />
    <item              android:id="@+id/nav_item3" />
    <item              android:id="@+id/nav_item4" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item5"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_item5"
        android:title="Home"
        android:visible="false"/>
</group>
```

**JAVA Code**

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(4).setChecked(true);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_item1:
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_item2:
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_item3:
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_item4:
                    return true;
            }

            // Default operation you want to perform

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone interested in a nice Kotlin solution, here's mine:

```
//disable the preselected first item
//<navigation> is the bottom navigation view

navigation.menu.getItem(0).isCheckable=false
```

Then in the selection listener, make sure that you'll show the user what he selected

```
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item: MenuItem ->
        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.option1 -> {
                item.isCheckable=true //here is the magic

                //notify the listener
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.option2 ->{
               item.isCheckable=true

                //notify the listener
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.option3 ->{
                //go to forgot user fragment
                item.isCheckable=true

                //notify the listener
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            else -> false
        }


    }
```

Finally , make a selector color so you can change easily in `color`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
<item android:color="@color/colorPrimary"  />
```

And add the selector to the navigation view

```
 app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_colors"
 app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_colors"
```

Now, if you need to change the colours, just change the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your onCreate method

```
mBottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId("ID OF YOUR MENU ITEM");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setCheckable` instead of `setChecked(false)` in line:

```
mBottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setCheckable(false);
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample project and by default there is no checked item. Just make sure you don't have any `navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.id)` on your code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to select a different tab and immediately after select the tab  I initially wanted.

```
bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.dummy_tab
bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.tab_to_select
```

The `setOnItemReselectedListener` disables reselect tab selections, but the navigationView has a default tab selected and don't render after creation because is invoking `setOnItemReselectedListener`

Tried the invisible solution but didn't work with programmatically bottomMenu creation.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if you still facing issue - just use this:

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setCheckable(false);
```

And it:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemReselectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemReselectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_home) {
            item.setCheckable(true);
        }
    }
});
```